# .net Create a list of objects where the object type is from a string

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net, dropzone.js, csvhelper

I need a way of creating a list of objects where the object is from a string

for example I want the below to be converted to a list of objects

```
Dim categoryList as IList(Of "classname") = new List(Of "class name")
```

end result

```
Dim categoryList As IList(Of BO.Store.Category) = New List(Of BO.Store.Category)
```

Thanks to xxbbcc for pointing me in the right direction. I have come up with the below solution which lets me upload any csv file and parse it into a list of x objects.

This works by uploading a file via dropzone along with a table name, object class name and a mapping class name. This now allows me to parse the contents of the file using csvhelper ready for importing into a temp table.

```
<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), BaseViewModelFilter>
    Function Upload(model As ImportUploadViewModel) As JsonResult

        Dim balUpload As BAL.Upload = New BAL.Upload()
        Dim balImport As BAL.Import = New BAL.Import()
        Dim folder As String = String.Format("{0}tmp\import\category", Server.MapPath("\"))

        Dim result = balUpload.SaveFiles(Request, folder, UserProfile.ID)

        Dim importClassType = Type.[GetType](String.Format("Roxybox.BO.{0}", model.EntityClass))
        Dim importClassMapType = Type.[GetType](String.Format("Roxybox.BO.{0}", model.EntityMap))

        Dim records As IList

        ' Import all successful files
        For Each successFile As String In result("success")

            ' Parse csv file
            Using sr = New StreamReader(String.Format("{0}\{1}", folder, successFile))
                Dim reader = New CsvReader(sr)

                reader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(importClassMapType)
                records = reader.GetRecords(importClassType).ToList()

            End Using

            For Each category In records
                Dim data As BO.Import = New BO.Import()
                With data
                    .EntityModel = model.EntityModel
                    .Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(category)
                    .UserProfileID = UserProfile.ID
                    .Filename = successFile
                    .Status = "pending"
                End With

                balImport.Save(data, UserProfile.ID)
            Next
        Next

        Return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) to create objects based on a string assembly name / type name. (The method has many other overloads, too.)

The call returns an `Object` so you'll have to cast it to a known type (for example, an interface type). As far as I know (I'm not a VB.Net expert) there's no way to define a variable with a string type name so you'll need to either

1. Store your instances in list of `Object`-s (this works but you don't really have usable objects this way).
2. Have your types all implement common, well-known interfaces. In this case you can create instances of your types using `CreateInstance` and then cast them to the known interface type. The type name will come from a string but the interface type must be hardcoded into the code.

For example (in C#):

```
  List<IMyInterface> oList = new List<IMyInterface> ();

  // ...

  // Loop through your assembly / type names
  ObjectHandle oHandle = Activator.CreateInstance(sAssemblyName, sTypeName);
  IMyInterface oInstance = oHandle.Unwrap() as IMyInterface; // null if wrong type

  if (oInstance!=null)
      oList.Add(oInstance);

  // ...

  // When you try using these instances, you can pull them from
  // the list and call functions through IMyInterface
  oList(3).CallInterfaceMember( /* params */ );
```

Don't attempt to cast the objects to a specific non-interface type - you create the instances from strings so you don't have actual knowledge of the real type - you only know what interfaces they *might* implement.

Comment: How would I use it to create a list of objects?

Comment: @adamias I'll add a small sample that shows it. Can you read / translate C#? (My C# is better than my VB.Net :)   )

Comment: That would be great. Yes I can convert it to vb.net. Thanks

Comment: @adamias I added a sample - let me know if you have more questions.